# Best placement for torque limiter?

Tags: gears, torque

Considering a stepper motor system that avoids the need for a limit switch, by turning until it can't turn anymore, and then a torque limiter takes up excess motion. When the motion stops, the shaft on the other side of the torque limiter is at a known position.

Curious if there's a better place to put such a torque limiter, on the low torque side of the system (immediately after the stepper motor) or on the high torque side of the system (on the other end of the gear train driven by the stepper motor)?

Springy printed torque limiter mechanism:
[image]

Comment: You speak as if there is only one way to make a torque limiter and one way to use a geared stepper setup. Here are at least two ways to build a torque limiter: spring-loaded and friction clutch. One can deal with multiple rotations and the other can't. Furthermore, geared stepper setups are used for both single and multi-rotation outputs. There is no one answer. However, it is easier to build a torque limiter that is triggered at higher forces than low forces due to available materials, but that's a torque limiter design issue, not a usage issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @DKNguyen, thank you.  This mechanism will have a 28BYJ-48 motor driving a 3-d printed set of gears, whose purpose is to increase the torque provided by the motor.   Pondering for the torque limiter, something similar to a Lego technics torque limiter (spring-loaded?), but with more stops, for more precise positioning.

Comment: @drone6502 What am I looking at? Are those teeth and spring acting as detents? SO that's capable of continuous rotation? If so, that's a third way to make a torque limiter (and a second way to make a spring-loaded torque limiter).  THe spring-loaded limiter I know of is like that a torque saver on an RC servo where the coil spring is arranged in a circular fashion between inner and outer concentric wheels so the wheels push against each other tangentially through the spring. It basically provides a bit of give to limit the torque and therefore does not work for continuous rotation.

Comment: Why not just let the steppers stall?

Comment: @Drew, Did not even consider that! I think that might work.